# What is the equivalent to getServerSideProps and getStaticProps in Next.js 14?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to understand how SSR/SSG/ISR rendering behavior works in Next.js version 14 with the new app router.
In the past I remember that Next.js offered reserved functions called `getServerSideProps` to fetch or do some work in the server (SSR) or the `getStaticProps` to generate the data during the build and cache it on the server (If I understand correctly).

What is the equivalent for these in Next.js 14 with the new app router?
Also, I saw in the docs that they are showing only examples with the `fetch` native API, Can I use axios library to make HTTP request and have the same behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: The version of Next.js has nothing to do with what you're asking, it's specific to the app router rather. You're still able to use the pages router with version 14

Answer (score 0):

All you ask is really very good documented in the App Router docs. Did you read the migration docs?

[Here you get good answers](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#step-6-migrating-data-fetching-methods). Now you should use the new `fetch` method for data fetching. With pages router you used `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps`.

What you do in Pages Router with `getServerSideProps` you do in App Router with React Server Components (RSC) with additional possibilities.

There is so much more to say. Really read carefully the excellent [App Router docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application)!